# Read Postgres CDC data with Logical Replication via Pgoutput plugin and decode it into textual format

Tags: postgresql, replication, pg-logical

Background: We are running Postgres v13.4 and have enabled logical replication for reading CDC data for a select few tables. We are using the pgoutput plugin and the basic setup is working fine.

Query: as we know, pgoutput returns data in binary format using the pg_logical_slot_peek_binary_changes or the pg_logical_slot_get_binary_changes. We need to convert this into textual format to parse and process it further. While there are some libs available to do this via applications like Java/Golang, we were intending to do it within db scripts / stored procs only. We haven't yet found a way and are seeking help regarding this.

Additional Note: We had looked at 2 other plugins - test_decoding doesn't support the publication_names option that's necessary and wal2json does not currently support publications, but it does provide the means to emulate them by the add/filter tables feature. However, this is also not the most ideal approach. So, we want to use pgoutput plugin only and need a way to decode the binary wal data.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, currently you can make use of publications only if you use the output-plugin pgoutput . Also remember to use ONLY keyword while creating the publication to get messages of only required tables in a DB.

`CREATE PUBLICATION name [ FOR TABLE [ ONLY ] table_name [ * ] [, ...] | FOR ALL TABLES ] [ WITH ( publication_parameter [= value] [, ... ] ) ]`

Refer - [creating publication for only some tables in a Postgres DB](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createpublication.html)

As you mentioned, pgoutput gives messages in encoded format and you have to decode it using algorithm specified here - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/protocol-logicalrep-message-formats.html.

I have made a python code that supports pgoutput along with the decoder that works perfectly OK for me. Also I have done some formatting in decoded output of pgoutput to get the messages in JSON format for better usability.

Here is the link to the same - https://github.com/PhantomHunt/cdc_postgres_logical_replication

Kindly do let me know if you encounter any bugs or issues in this code.

Comment: Could you please explain how to use your scripts in Linux PG installed server ?